# How to clone a eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse

I have an instalation of eclipse Juno, I mean a directory as you know, in this directory i did a final Project of University in J2EE but my computer was afected by CryptoWall 3.0 and all the files were encrypted. I do a new installation of eclipse Juno, but when I compare both directories the new don't have the same files, specialy the directory called eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\

Comment: eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\ contains temporary files and changes all the time, you would not expect it to be the same for two installations.

Answer (score -2):

Probably your eclipse installation is corrupted, you need to  reinstall it for the fix.